# HLS folder is not getting created in NGINX-RTMP

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, http-live-streaming

This is my nginx configuration file. I am using OBS to stream some media files to my nginx server. The /tmp/live/ folder is getting created but /tmp/live/1080/index.m3u8 is not getting created.

> https://gist.github.com/Eta-Meson/2f88a91ad57704247dcc5c9cf4a89e35

I have kept my configuration file in this gist.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see any reference to "1080" in your nginx.conf. I see _low, _mid, _high, and _hd720. Do you see those? E.g. http://yourip/live/key_mid/index.m3u8

If not your nginx probably doesn't have enough permissions to execute ffmpeg.

Comment: $name in my conf file refers to 1080 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by looking at *ffmpeg* logs.

I found out that my system does not have *libvo_aacenc* audio codec. So I changed that to *aac* and everything worked fine.